# Process Monitor Equivalent in Linux

Tags: linux, debugging

In Windows when I wanted to debug applications that can't open a file I used to use Process Monitor which told you the exact path the application was trying to open. Is there a similar tool or ideally command for Linux (Ubuntu)? (i.e that can list failed calls to open file).

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/97844/how-can-i-determine-what-process-has-a-file-open-in-linux

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`lsof`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) to check which files are open or you can use [`strace`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to trace the `open` system call, in case the open does not work.

```
strace -e open cat doesnotexist.txt
```

for example is going to tell you (somewhat verbose), that `open` returned -1 and `errno` was set to `ENOENT`, meaning the file does not exist.

Comment: that does not seem to tell you the absolute paths of the file it  attempted to open though :( i.e it returns something like: open("ddf.cat", O_RDONLY)    = -1) and not  open("/home/whatever/ddf.cat")

Comment: It tells you exactly which arguments open was called with (strace - system call trace). If the path is relative, the path is relative in the strace output. However you should know the working directory of your program, or otherwise, that may well be the source of error you look for.